# hide elements on scrolling and not in focus

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a list of forms and have them disabled and only the form in focus is enabled. Then when scrolling down that one form is disabled and the next form in focus is enabled. Here is the code I am messing around with:

(The reason I posted the code below is that each form element currently is not disabled when not in focus. I would like only a few elements to be enabled at a time when in focus and others to be disabled)

```js
function SubmitName() {
  var form = document.getElementById("InputName");
  var elements = form.elements;
  for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
    elements[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
.body {}

.buttonTans {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width .5s;
}

.buttonTans:hover {
  width: 100px;
}

.formsize {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.ResizeForms {
  width: 120px;
}

.ResizeForms:hover {
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width .5s;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<form id="InputName">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms formsize" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms formsize" type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
<form id="InputName2">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
<form id="InputName3">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
<form id="InputName4">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
<form id="InputName5">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
<form id="InputName6">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
<form id="InputName7">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
<form id="InputName8">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
<form id="InputName9">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
<form id="InputName10">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
```

You can see what I am talking aobut here if you select something like "market survery"

https://admin.typeform.com/gallery/workspaces/11216029#/

TLDR:

How do you make forms disabled when not in direct view on scrolling (one or just a forms enabled at a time when in focus)?

Edit

I managed to use the event listener scroll solution Thanks to felixmosh. Here is my modified code. Stille tweaking it a bit, but I'm going to post it so anyone else can also play around with it:

```js
function SubmitName() {
  var form = document.getElementById("InputName");
  var elements = form.elements;
  for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
    elements[i].disabled = true;
  }
}


var yPositionForm = new Array(10); //array which stores yposition of each form
var formIdName = ["InputName", "InputName2", "InputName3", "InputName4", "InputName5", "InputName6", "InputName7", "InputName8", "InputName9", "InputName10"];

function findTop(element) {
  var rec = document.getElementById(element).getBoundingClientRect();
  return rec.top;
}

function findFormPositions() {
  for (var k = 0; k <= yPositionForm.length - 1; k++) {
    yPositionForm[k] = findTop(formIdName[k]);
  }
}

function disableFormElements() {

  var formName = formIdName[0];
  var formString = formIdName[0];

  var j = 0;

  while (j <= formIdName.length - 1) {
    var form = document.getElementById(formIdName[j]);
    var elements = form.elements;
    for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
      elements[i].disabled = true;
      elements[i].style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
    j++;
  }

  //do something here to mess with opacity
}

function disableAllButTop() {

  var formName = formIdName[0];
  var formString = formIdName[0];

  var j = 1;

  while (j <= formIdName.length - 1) {
    var form = document.getElementById(formIdName[j]);
    var elements = form.elements;
    for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
      elements[i].disabled = true;
      elements[i].style.opacity = 0.5; //do something here to mess with opacity
    }
    j++;
  }
}


disableAllButTop(); //start with all forms disabled but the first one

var last_known_scroll_position = 0;
var ticking = false;



function doSomethingOnScroll(scroll_pos) {
  // do something with the scroll position
  disableFormElements();
  findFormPositions();

  for (var k = 0; k <= yPositionForm.length - 1; k++) {
    if (yPositionForm[k] <= scroll_pos + 315 && yPositionForm[k] >= scroll_pos - 80) {
      EnableForum(formIdName[k]);
    }
  }
}

function EnableForum(name) {
  var form = document.getElementById(name);
  var elements = form.elements;
  for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
    elements[i].disabled = false;
    elements[i].style.opacity = 1; //do something here to mess with opacity
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

  if (!ticking) {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomethingOnScroll(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;

  }

});
```

```css
.body {}

.testVisible.visible {
  display: block;
}

.buttonTans {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width .5s;
}

.buttonTans:hover {
  width: 100px;
}

.formsize {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.ResizeForms {
  width: 120px;
}

.ResizeForms:hover {
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width .5s;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<form id="InputName" class="testVisible">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms formsize" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms formsize" type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>

<form id="InputName2">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>


<form id="InputName3">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>


<form id="InputName4">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>

<form id="InputName5">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>

<form id="InputName6">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>


<form id="InputName7">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>

<form id="InputName8">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>


<form id="InputName9">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>


<form id="InputName10">
  First name:<br>
  <input id="firstname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input id="lastname" class="ResizeForms" type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <input id="submitName" class="buttonTans" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitName()">
</form>
```

Comment: The end goal of an SO post is a question. What is yours? Do you have some specific problems with the provided code, or you just wanted us to know, that you're doing on this project?

Comment: There are many options to listen to the event using `window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {})` or any spy-scroll lib available out there

Comment: @ felixmosh thank you, I think that may be what I am looking for. I am still bit confused on how to tell which one, in particular, is focused. But, I'll try messing around with that. @Teemu  I thought I tried to make it clear I wanted one form to be viewed at a time. The code I posted was just what I am working with it does not do what I want yet. The link I posted shows what I want to happen. I added a TLDR to avoid any confusion.

Comment: You made clear what you want, but you didn't say anything about the problems with the code, what does it do instead of the expected results. It is the most important part of the question.

Comment: @Teemu ok understood.Originally you stated "The end goal of an SO post is a question. What is yours?" So, I thought you missed the question. I am, glad it was clear. The reason I posted the code was to show an example of what I am working if someone wanted to modify it accordingly to give a more detailed answer if they wanted to. I'll try to make the reason why I posted the code more clear in the future thank you. I managed to find examples based on felixmosh's answer and modified the code for others to play around with.

Comment: @felixmosh  I wish you posted this as a separate answer so I can mark it as the solution as I was able to search the web based on that piece of information and create a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options to listen to the scroll event one of them is using 
[scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll),
`window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {})` others can be done using any spy-scroll lib available out there.

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot :D